# How I can execute extern Module Commands on a remote Computer in Powershell without install the Module?

Tags: powershell, updates, remote-access, execute, winrm

I want to execute powershell commands on a remote computer and I use a extern Module on the localhost. I tested it and get the message that I don't can use the command on the remote computer but locally it works.

So I have installed the module on the remote computer via Import-Module and it works.

But this is bad and I want not install the module on every computer in the company.

**Here is my PS Script:**

```
$cred = Get-Credential

$isConnect = Test-WSMan edv-004

if($isConnect){

    #Get-WUHistory is from a extern Module and list the Updatehistory of a computer
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName edv-004 -ScriptBlock { Get-WUHistory } -Credential $cred

    Write-Host "Skript wurde auf ausgeführt..."
}
```

Before I run this script I have do this:

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts * -Force  #for testing 
Restart-Service WinRM
```

So how I can execute extern module commands without install it on the remote computer? :/

Answer (score 1):

You can import a module from a [shared location](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/08/powertip-import-a-powershell-module-from-a-shared-location.aspx) (if your execution policy allows it):

```psh
Invoke-Command -ComputerName edv-004 -ScriptBlock {
  Import-Module \\server\share\YourModule
  Get-WUHistory
} -Credential $cred
```

but you can't run a function from a module without importing the module first.

Comment: this is a good idea but not that what I want...the problemn is I must do on every computer the execution policy :(

Comment: If you are managing a domain and it would be easier to set execution policy through registry settings, then you could use this method to update that first: http://blogs.technet.com/b/operationsguy/archive/2011/04/21/remotely-tweak-powershell-execution-policies.aspx.

Comment: You need to change the execution policy on each host anyway, since the default is `Restricted`. Do it at the same time you enable PSRemoting.

Comment: Hi @AnsgarWiechers with the Invoke-Command cmdlet, can I execute the script1.ps1 where the script and the modules are installed on the server rather than on my computer locally?